# How to make a new line in raphael JS text?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I was trying to use `<br> and \n` , but it seems not to work inside text in raphael js.

I need it to be inside one text, because I am using multiple resize effects in different languages (one language has three lines and one 4 lines).

My code that is not working:

```
var mytext = paper.text(150, 250, "Line1<br>Line2");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works with `\n`, see [a live demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nbt5K/), illustrating this.

Also have a look at the [Raphaël reference](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.text), here's a pullquote from the entry on `text()`:

> Draws a text string. If you need line breaks, put “\n” in the string.

Comment: Hmm, it is working now ;), I had to do something wrong the first time. Thanks a lot.